# Where do I get BootstrapValidartor cdns and how do I use them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Im looking for the new bootstrapvalidator cdns but I cant find them. I thought I had them but the plugin is not working I have....

```
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.3/js/bootstrapValidator.min.js" integrity="sha256-PbFF1Mdg86urwOYXWNJPP4z5Ge9KLp6KXX1NURQY8Ho=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

and

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.3/css/bootstrapValidator.min.css" integrity="sha256-YvAujCECPPslDy9IUX/t20rU7WANfRpYMtIusXyn/ho=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
```

I cant get the IDE to see bootStrapvalidator...
this is my code:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">

    <h:head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"></meta>

        <title>#{loginMsgs.pageTitle}</title>

       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous"></link>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.3/css/bootstrapValidator.min.css" integrity="sha256-YvAujCECPPslDy9IUX/t20rU7WANfRpYMtIusXyn/ho=" crossorigin="anonymous" />

    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-2 col-sm-1 col-xs-12"/>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-8 col-sm-10 col-xs-12">
                    <h:form id="LoginForm">
                        <h1 id="loginFormHeader">#{loginMsgs.login}</h1>
                        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                                <p:inputText  id="userName" p:placeholder="UserName" id="userName" class="form-control" value="#{loginBean.userName}"></p:inputText>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                         <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i></span>
                                <p:inputText  p:placeholder="Password" id="password" class="form-control" value="#{loginBean.passWord}" required="true" requiredMessage="Nope" validatorMessage=""></p:inputText>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <h:commandButton class="btn btn-block btn-success" value="#{loginMsgs.loginButton}"></h:commandButton>

                    </h:form>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-2 col-sm-1 col-xs-12"/>
            </div>

        </div>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.3/js/bootstrapValidator.min.js" integrity="sha256-PbFF1Mdg86urwOYXWNJPP4z5Ge9KLp6KXX1NURQY8Ho=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready
            (
                    function()
                    {
                        $('#LoginForm').bootstrapvalidator
                        ({

                        })
                    }
            )
        </script>
    </h:body>

</html>
```

is there something I am doing wrong, or do I have bad links; or is one of them out of place or missing ? I know I have JSF in here but that should not matter.

Comment: What error msg is displayed in the console?

Comment: no errors display

Comment: in your console type: $('#LoginForm').bootstrapvalidator                        ({

                        }) and check what error you get or if the validator is triggered .

Comment: the output console?

Comment: Yes the output console

Comment: You're loading bootstrap 4 beta js (although you load bootstrap 3 css). Reading the bootstrapvalidator page, it only works with bootstrap 3. For bootstrap 4, they offer now http://formvalidation.io/

Comment: Im using netbeans it will not let me type in the console

Comment: oh ok you know where i can get 3

Comment: https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/

Comment: k I found it but it still is not seeing it

Comment: <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Comment: Translating to the HTML elements, with the bootstrap 3 CDN your code works for me in fiddle. Here you have the example https://fiddle.jshell.net/rigobauer/155ho3o6/

Comment: Yeah I copied that and put into an html and it works... so i guess i cant use the validator with jsf and just do it manually with regex. I just dont know how to triger the valadator form colors with jsf.